# Declaring a global barrier and initializing it locally

Tags: c++

I have this implementation for a thread barrier

```
class my_barrier
{

public:
    my_barrier(int count)
        : thread_count(count)
        , counter(0)
        , waiting(0)
    {}

    void wait()
    {
        //fence mechanism
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
        ++counter;
        ++waiting;
        cv.wait(lk, [&] {return counter >= thread_count; });
        cv.notify_one();
        --waiting;
        if (waiting == 0)
        {
            //reset barrier
            counter = 0;
        }
        lk.unlock();
    }

private:
    std::mutex m;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    int counter;
    int waiting;
    int thread_count;
};
```

What I'm trying to do is to declare an instance of this class globally but initialize it only in main , because i read the number of threads from console , so i don't know the value for initialization before runtime, could you help me with this one?

Comment: What's wrong with a local variable?

Comment: i have to pass it to a worker function for multiple threads, and i can't manage to make it work

Comment: Sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/358508?).

Comment: @PasserBy we were suggested to find a solution of making it global, a local variable is only the last solution

Comment: Probably relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38927751 [Here's a tiny example too](https://godbolt.org/z/Yesbjb)